# understanding relation between post-css grunt plugin and autoprefixer

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Hey guys I was just messing around with grunt and came across this powerful plugin **[HERE](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss#usage)**, grunt-postcss. Its quite a powerful plugin , it helped me prefix a file of animations in less than a scound (I guess that's what grunt is all about.). Anyways, Now I see the following following command line instructions for post-css.

```
$ npm install grunt-postcss pixrem autoprefixer cssnano
```

If I remember correctly `autoprefixer` was an independent grunt plugin that's been depreciated, but what does it have in relation to post-css ? and also what do there other plugins I.E.  `pixrem` `cssnano` , have to do with `post-css`  ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed autoprefixer was a independent plugin, but now is included inside the postcss, for performance reasons:

> Unlike the traditional approach with separate plugins, `grunt-postcss`
>   allows you to parse and save CSS only once applying all
>   post-processors in memory and thus reducing your build time. PostCSS
>   is also a simple tool for writing your own CSS post-processors.

https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss#why-would-i-use-this

**What do there other plugins eg:  `pixrem`, `cssnano`, have to do with post-css?**

There are plugins extras, that you may use or not:

- `pixrem`: Add fallbacks for rem units
- `cssnano`: Minify the result